# Custom tag being removed from text editor

Tags: widgets, visual-editor, scripts

I have visual composer installed. I have a special "weather widget" that I need to add to a page, but it keeps getting stripped when I add it into a text block.

```
 <wx:widget type="alerts" template="simple" location="USMT0163" expanded="default"></wx:widget>
```

What would I need to do to not strip out this wx:widget blocks?